# How can I rearrange a Google Sheet using the data within the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, transpose

I get massive serialized spreadsheets in the following format:

```
PN   SN  Qty
1    24   3
2    25   1
3    26   7
```

I need to write a Sheets script that can rearrange the data so that the headers are gone, and the quantities are extrapolated, then cleared.

For example, the desired result would be:

```
1  24
1  24
1  24
2  25
3  26
3  26
3  26
3  26
3  26
3  26
3  26
```

I have tried writing a few recursive statements to achieve this, however once I started adding in new rows to the sheet my loop breaks.  I've tried hundreds of different iterations of what I know should be a fairly simple task but alas, I am well out of practice. I fear at this point I am fixated on the wrong idea.  Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use google apps script.

Try the following formula:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(A2:A&"♠", C2:C), ,999^99), "♠")))),ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(B2:B&"♠", C2:C), ,999^99), "♠"))))}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Different approach, same result:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER(REPT(A2:A&"\"&B2:B&"^",C2:C),A2:A<>""),"^",0,1)),"Select * Where Col1 <>''"),"\"))
```

I'm adding this only because different people may find one or the other easier to understand and apply. There is no practical or performance gain to this formula over the great suggestion given by Marios.

NOTE: This formula makes use of an as yet unofficial Google Scripts function, FLATTEN.